# .htaccess link css is not linking

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to .htaccess so bear with me.

I am trying to have my URL look like:

```
http://example.com/login
```

Using .htaccess it uses:

```
http://example.com/index.php?url=login
```

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The problem with this is that when I try to access `http://example.com/asset/style.css` it just shows my index.php without being able to use my css. How can I change this to be able to use my css files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php?url=$1 - [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Now that I rechecked this on a different server, if I type in example.com/hello and I have an if statment for if url equals 'hello' my echo inside will not pop up. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you var_dump($_GET) ?